# Why Activiti sequenceFlow sourceRef and aretargetRef are not correct?

Tags: activiti

I used the Eclipse activiti plugin to draw the activiti flow, but the sourceRef and aretargetRef are not correct, why flow1-4 related to last task??

```
<process id="simpleProcess" name="simpleProcess" isExecutable="true">
    <extensionElements>
      <activiti:executionListener event="end" class="com.example.activiti.listener.SimpleProcessEndListener"></activiti:executionListener>
    </extensionElements>
    <startEvent id="startevent" name="Start"></startEvent>
    <userTask id="userTask2" name="主管审批">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="com.example.activiti.listener.LeaderCheckListener"></activiti:taskListener>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <userTask id="userTask3" name="总监审批" activiti:assignee="1004"></userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="userTask4" targetRef="userTask4"></sequenceFlow>
    <userTask id="userTask4" name="总经理审批" activiti:assignee="1005"></userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow4" sourceRef="userTask4" targetRef="userTask4"></sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="endevent" name="End">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:executionListener event="end" class="com.example.activiti.listener.SimpleProcessEndListener"></activiti:executionListener>
      </extensionElements>
    </endEvent>
    <userTask id="userTask1" name="请假申请"></userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent" targetRef="userTask4"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="userTask4" targetRef="userTask4"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow5" sourceRef="userTask4" targetRef="endevent"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following flow elements:

```
<sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="userTask4" targetRef="userTask4"></sequenceFlow>
<sequenceFlow id="flow4" sourceRef="userTask4" targetRef="userTask4"></sequenceFlow>
<sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="userTask4" targetRef="userTask4"></sequenceFlow>
```

are likely a result of you "fat fingering" during the modelling.
It is very easy to start dragging a flow line and then releasing in the same activity as you stared, unfortunately the eclipse modeler doesnt realize this is an invalid sequence flow and adds it to the model.

As far as I know, the eclipse modeler is no longer maintained (I could be wrong about this).

The best you can do is use a text editor to remove the erroneous sequence flow elements.

Greg